# TestNG No tests found. Nothing was run

Tags: java, testng

I am facing a strange problem with my TestNg code. When I run the testng class without dataprovider my tests run successfully and gets failed which is expected for me.
But when I keep my dataprovider in the class for that test. Testng gives an error :
**[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run**
Below is my code: Please let me know the solution or suggest what I am doing wrong TestNG Version: 6.14.3

```
package api.tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import api.config.Base;
import api.data.xlutility_read;
import api.services.GooglePlace;

public class GoogleAddPlaceTest extends Base {

    public static GooglePlace GP = null;
    public static xlutility_read ER = null;
    public HashMap<String, String> requestMap = null;

    public GoogleAddPlaceTest() throws IOException {
        super();

    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void Setup() throws IOException {
        GP = new GooglePlace();
        Base.setResources();
        // ER =
    }

    @DataProvider()
    public Object[][] getExcelRows() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        ER = new xlutility_read("D:\\ApiData.xlsx");

        Object[][] object = new Object[ER.getRowCount(1) - 2][1];
        int rNum = 3;
        while (!ER.isRowEmpty(1, rNum) && rNum <= ER.getRowCount(1)) {
            requestMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {

                requestMap = ER.ExcelToHashMap(1, rNum);

            }
            object[rNum - 3][0] = requestMap;
            rNum++;
        }

        ER.closeFile();

        return object;

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "getExcelRows")
    public void testAddPlaceApi(HashMap<Object, Object> requestMap) throws IOException {
        try {
            ER = new xlutility_read("D:\\ApiData.xlsx");
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int testRowNum = ER.getRowNum(1, "testAddPlaceApi", 0);
        if (testRowNum != -1) {
            if (ER.getCellData(1, testRowNum, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                GP.deletePlaceApi(GP.addPlaceApi(GP.jsonAsMap(requestMap)));
            } else {
                throw new SkipException("Test case run Flag is N : So Skipped.");
            }
        }

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearUp() throws IOException {
        Base.freeResources();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post complete test class. This also has compilation errors such as duplicate imports. You may want to fix them first.

Comment: as I can see in this class, there is no method with "@Test" tag, and not sure how are you invoking your tests, if with Testng.xml, make sure the class specified there has methods with `@Test` annotations

Comment: There is @Test Method if you scroll down the code window : that is "public void testAddPlaceApi(HashMap<Object, Object> requestMap)"

Comment: I have removed duplicate Imports @shankulk tried  running again same error. I dont know when i remove my dataprovider my test runs and it fails but when i keep my dataprovider it says no test found

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue. Did You resolved this

Answer (score 1):

From the [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders):

> A @Test method specifies its Data Provider with the dataProvider
>   attribute.  This name must correspond to a method on the same class
>   annotated with @DataProvider(name="...") with a matching name.

So you have to bind your data provider method to test method by name:

```
@DataProvider(name = "data")
public Object[][] getExcelRows() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
   ...
}
```

and

```
@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public void testAddPlaceApi(HashMap<Object, Object> requestMap) throws IOException {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using excel sheets to store your test data? If yes, add one more column as Execute with value as Y.