# "No tests found for given includes" when using TestNG with Groovy

Tags: groovy, testng

I'm trying to use Test NG with Groovy. I implemented a simple test class, but whenever I try to run it I get the following error:

```
No tests found for given includes: [tests.OTP.get]
```

Here is what the `tests.OTP` class looks like:

```
class OTP{
    public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(HomePage.class.getName())
    String environment = 'qatesting'
    String number = '0769878787'
    @Test
    def get(){
//        SoapuiOTP s = new SoapuiOTP(environment,number)
//        s.getOTP()
        log.info("hello")
        Assert.assertEquals(0,System.getProperty("SOAPUI_OTP"))
        log.info System.getProperty('SOAPUI_OTP')
    }
}
```

I use the play button (IntelliJ) next to the `def get()` to run the test but i get the same error on class level. Please assist, I've tried invaliding my cache and restarting. I have looked at [TestNG No tests found. Nothing was run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590402/testng-no-tests-found-nothing-was-run) and 
[TestNG - no tests were found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727287/testng-no-tests-were-found), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `def` with `void` in the method annotated with `@Test`. As the documentation says:

> Test methods are annotated with `@Test`. Methods annotated with `@Test` that happen to return a value will be ignored, unless you set `allow-return-values` to true in your testng.xml:
>
> ```
> <test allow-return-values="true">
> ```
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-methods</sup>

The `def` return type compiles to `Object`, not `void`, so TestNG ignores this method by default.

This misconception is not TestNG specific and can be done in JUnit as well: [Running Groovy test cases with JUnit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52925055/2194470)

Comment: Thank you, being taught in java and changing over to groovy has its disadvantages. All of my methods were suffering lol. Thank you :)